# Are there laws in India against child violence outside schools?

Tags: criminal-law, india, battery

For example there are many beggar children who are physically hurt by people like shop owners and the like to leave the premises etc. Is this punishable by any law?

Comment: Are you talking about violence against children, violence against children that takes place only outside schools, or anti-begging laws?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Although there are numerous child-protection laws, there is nothing specific for (beggar) children in this scenario so it would fall within Criminal Force, an offence contrary to [section 350](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46117&sectionno=350&orderno=390) Indian Penal Code:

> Whoever intentionally uses force to any person, without that person's consent ... or intending ... or knowing it to be likely that by the use of such force he will cause injury, fear or annoyance to the person to whom the force is used, is said to use criminal force to that other.

The punishment for which may be found at [section 352](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46119&sectionno=352&orderno=392)

> Whoever ... uses criminal force to any person otherwise than on grave and sudden provocation given by that person, shall be punished with imprisonment ... for a term which may extend to three months, or with fine which may extend to five hundred rupees, or with both.

For completeness "Force" is described by [section 349](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46116&sectionno=349&orderno=389) as:

> A person is said to use force to another if he causes motion, change of motion, or cessation of motion to that other, or if he causes to any substance such motion, or change of motion, or cessation of motion as brings that substance into contact with any part of that other's body, or with anything which that other is wearing or carrying, or with anything so situated that such contact affects that other's sense of feeling...
>
> [*A substance could be, for example, a broom handle or a pan of water*]

Also, for completeness there's the alternative of Assault under [section 351](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46118&sectionno=351&orderno=391) if no force is used.